# Deal with multidimensional array with object and integer under PHP

Tags: php

I have to count the total number of miss item, between two object with PHP, which are define in the following class:

```
 <?php
class Module {
    var $nD;
    var $nC;
    var $nA;
    function __construct($nD, $nC, $nA) {
        $this->nD = $nD;
        $this->nC = $nC;
        $this->nA = $nA;
    }
    function toString() {
        return $this->nD . "-" . $this->nC . "-" . $this->nA . "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

There are some fixed Modules, which are the following:

```
$mods = array (
        'mod1' => new module ( 4, 3, 3 ),
        'mod2' => new module ( 5, 3, 2 ),
        'mod3' => new module ( 4, 4, 2 ),
        'mod4' => new module ( 5, 4, 1 ),
        'mod5' => new module ( 4, 5, 1 ),
        'mod6' => new module ( 3, 5, 2 ),
        'mod7' => new module ( 3, 4, 3 ) 
);
```

So for example, as input, I type the following Module(2,4,3), and the result of the total differences, for the case of mod1 will be:
4-2 = 2, 3-4 = -1 ->0 (just the positive value), 3-3 = 0 so total 2+0+0 = 2
for mod2 will be:
5-2 = 3, 3-4 = -1 ->0 (just the positive value should be added), 2-3 = -1 -> (just the positive value) so total 3

This are the code, to calculate the value of the differences:

```
<?php
include 'module.php';
function getmodules($id = null) {
    $mods = array (
            'mod1' => new module ( 4, 3, 3 ),
            'mod2' => new module ( 5, 3, 2 ),
            'mod3' => new module ( 4, 4, 2 ),
            'mod4' => new module ( 5, 4, 1 ),
            'mod5' => new module ( 4, 5, 1 ),
            'mod6' => new module ( 3, 5, 2 ),
            'mod7' => new module ( 3, 4, 3 ) 
    );

    if (null !== $id) {
        return isset ( $mods [$id] ) ? $mods [$id] : false;
    } else {
        return $mods;
    }
}

$module = new Module ( 2, 3, 4 );
$array = array ();
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i ++) {
    $par = getmodules ( 'mod' . $i );
    $num = 0;
    if ($par->nD > $module->nD) {
        $num += $par->nD - $module->nD;
    }
    if ($par->nC > $module->nC) {
        $num += $par->nC - $module->nC;
    }
    if ($par->nA > $module->nA) {
        $num += $par->nA - $module->nA;
    }

}
?>
```

So what I want, is to have a sort of HashMap, with as key value the Module for example (new Module(4,4,2)) and as the value the $num variable. 
Also, as next step, I want to order the HashMap with by crescent value of $num. 
So the output will be something like that:

$output = array()[the object Module mod1 => $num of mod1,the object Module mod2,$num of mod2];

I hope that the question is clear. In case of doubts, just ask.

Comment: I, seems, understood all all  till 'as next step' and nothing after :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written as understood

```
class Module {
    static $matrix = array(
        array ( 4, 3, 3 ),
        array ( 5, 3, 2 ),
        array ( 4, 4, 2 ),
        array ( 5, 4, 1 ),
        array ( 4, 5, 1 ),
        array ( 3, 5, 2 ),
        array ( 3, 4, 3 ) 
    );
    var $values = array(0,0,0);
    function __construct($nD, $nC, $nA) {
        $this->values = array($nD, $nC, $nA);
    }
    function toString() {
        return implode(' - ', $this->values). "<br>";
    }
    function hash() {
      foreach (self::$matrix as $m) {
        $nm = 0;
        foreach ($this->values as $key => $val)  {
          $n = $m[$key] - $val;
          $nm += $n > 0 ? $n : 0;
          }
        $num[] = $nm;
        }
      return $num;
    }
}

$module = new Module ( 2, 3, 4 );

// here you can set matrix by Module::matrix

var_dump($module->hash());
```

output :

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(4)
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [6]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've not totally understood the var_dump(); method. By the way the solution is very close ! How Can I get the Module object, which has the lowest value of $num ? Can you modify the code for this purpose ?

Comment: Can I get the Module object, -ie. really line of mattrix?

Comment: It must be returned by hash  method?

Comment: if tow or some line have the same result, retirning 1st?

Comment: Well, what I want is to have the Module object with toString(); So the method should be (I write it in Java for simplicity) public Module getBestModule(Module actualModule);

Comment: I know can be more than one that are best module, but for simplicity I want the first one. Usually the best, should be the one with $num = 0, and the highest number of $nA value (so 3 or 2 or 1), but this will be harder to code.

Comment: $module->hash() return array of nums whith keys - numbers of line in matrix. Take from it the line you need by any  condition. I don't see a problem to find minimum in array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78829/discussion-between-i-love-coding-and-splash58).